# Keep getting error while trying to mount external HDD with LVM2 format, using Knoppix from live USB, please help

Tags: mount, hard-disk, external-hdd, lvm

I am computer savvy, but fairly new to Linux, so forgive me if not technical enough.

I have a 3TB external HDD, a Seagate, and it used to be a NAS, but the Ethernet portion failed, so I have plugged it directly into my desktop computer via SATA interface. The desktop is maybe 5 years old, Athlon dual core 4 GB RAM, etc. I set it up to dual boot Windows 7 and a yet to be decided Linux distro.

So I am trying Knoppix, the most current version, and I am running it from a live USB stick:

- I can see the HDD,
- it has several partitions on it,
- the main one is LVM2,
- but I can't mount it.

The drive has data on it that I am trying to access.

I have searched around the internet, including this forum, and found some helpful suggestions regarding LVM, but nothing seems to work. I still can't mount it or access the data on it, as everything I try results in an error. How can I access this HDD?

I can provide any additional info, as required.

**update**

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# vgchange -ay vg1
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" now active

mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /mnt/tmp
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In Some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

*Update*
Ok, thank you @Hauke, i tried using your command and got the same error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
in some cases info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into this exact scenario today seagate central nas with failed network port. simplest lvm setup you can imagine, but impossible to mount the ext4 filesystem even though I can't find any tool that reports an error. I ended up pulling the files I needed using debugfs

Comment: found reason in dmesg "bad block size 65536" others have reported mounting via fuse to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have forgotten to activate the volumes ("normal" distros activate everything but live distros do not). You can either activate a whole volume group (even if you do not need all volumes) with

```
vgchange -ay vgname
```

or just the logical volumes you need with

```
lvchange -ay vgname/lvname
```

`lvs` shows you which volumes are active (the `a` column). Run it before and after the above command for comparison.

Comment: I tried and this is what I got:

Comment: root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# vgchange -ay vg1  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1" now active  Do I now try to mount it? Can you please tell me how to do the command?

Comment: mkdir /mnt/tmp  mount /dev/vg1/lv1 /mnt/tmp  mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error  In Some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so

Comment: @ScottA You should usually put such bis command output as edit into your question because it is much easier to read than in a comment. The mount problem is not related to your LVM problem; you just used the wrong command. You need: `mount -t auto /dev/vg1/lv1 /mnt/tmp`